# Django and SaaS. How to use separate database for each Django site?

Tags: python, django, saas

I am creating a SaaS project with Django. 
I decided to use [django-saas-kit](https://github.com/zhaque/django-saas-kit) for the user subscriptions and multi-accounts part.

Ideally I would like to be able to create a new site for each user and a separate database.
Does the sites framework support this? How can it be implemented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a "clients" folder, and a subdirectory per client. In each subdirectory, create a site_settings.py file as such:

```
import os.path

# import global settings
from settings import *

# this is barely just the name of the client dir, you might want to use that
SITE_NAME = __file__.split('/')[-2]
# this is the directory of the client website
CLIENT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': SITE_NAME,
        'USER': SITE_NAME,
        'PASSWORD': 'some random password',
    }  
}

# you might want this too so that each client have his own MEDIA_ROOT
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CLIENT_ROOT, 'upload')
```

Then don't forget to use the --settings switch for management commands. For example:

```
./manage.py syncdb --settings=clients.demo.site_settings
```

Don't forget that each client will require to have his own extra stuff. For example, if you use haystack with whoosh, you need to add this so that it doesn't get mixed up between clients:

```
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = os.path.join(CLIENT_ROOT, 'whoosh')
```

Or with django-zstask:

```
ZTASKD_URL = 'ipc:///tmp/%s_ztask.sock' % SITE_NAME
```

Or with JohnnyCache:

```
JOHNNY_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX=SITE_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer :). I also had the question about background tasks that you provided an answer for using ztaskd. I am using celery right now. Is there a solution for it ? And also please tell me which do you prefer celery or ztaskd?

Comment: if using djkombu for transport, then messages are passed through the database and no conflict should be possible. But i don't know celery that well...

Comment: I didn't answer: first I tried celery and it works well. But then I tried django-ztask and it's pretty much the same for basic needs except it way simpler - particularly it installs much faster and requires less care.

Comment: I finally got to try django-ztask . Currently I am facing the problem that it only sees the global settings.py, it doesn't know anything about the clients settings files. The ZTASKD_URL defaults to the tcp://127.0.0.1:5555/ instead of the ipc link. I followed the README on github for the installation. Anything I missed ?

Comment: It looks like you missed --settings, maybe you could make another question with more details ?

Comment: Thanks jpic. I asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429274/django-and-saas-ztask-for-backgroud-tasks