# Django and SaaS + Ztask for background tasks

Tags: python, django, saas, zeromq

I asked a question before on how to create a SaaS application using Django
[Django and SaaS. How to use separate database for each Django site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500142/django-and-saas-how-to-use-separate-database-for-each-django-site)

Now when a user creates a new instance for himself I simply create a new settings.py file for him, and create an apache configuration for his subdomain. Now when a user tries to access his instance he can only see his own database, so we have total separation of data.

Now there is a problem when trying to do background processes while having these separate databases. Background processes should be specific to each instance acting only on this instance data. ZTask daemon takes a settings file to start. The question is do I have to start a separate ztaskd process for each Django instance? or can I start ztaskd once for all instances?

Comment: I use this script to manage my ztaskd instances, but I don't have time to explain it ... hope this can be useful to inspire you https://gist.github.com/2585486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ztaskd` works within a context of particular Django instance, so you cannot share one ZTask daemon for multiple Django instances.

You should run `ztaskd` for each Django instance with it's local settings. Basically start it using

```
python manage.py ztaskd --settings=clients.site_settings &
```

Remember to have non-conflicting `ZTASKD_URL` for each instance. For local `ztaskd`

```
ZTASKD_URL = 'ipc:///tmp/%s_ztask.sock' % SITE_NAME
```

as suggested in [an answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500200/60711) is good idea.